# Using AWS Custom metrics in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I've created a custom aws cloudwatch metric to monitor a process running on OS level using pattern. I've tried creating alarm using Terraform but unable to use the custom metric entries like "pid_finder" and "pattern" in the code whereas it is possible to do in AWS console directly. Any suggestions ?

[image]

I checked bunch of online blogs but none could provide solution for this.

Comment: Was able to resolve the issue using "dimensions" in the terraform code.